# How to check if char doesnt exist in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

Say we have the user input a name that is a string `"william"` and then the user enters the character that they want to find the index of.

```
 using namespace std;
 string name;
 char characterToFind;
 cout << "Enter a name ";
 cin >> name;
 cout << "Enter a character to find ";
 cin >> characterToFind;
```

We then want to find the index of the character in the `name` string array.

```
for (int j = 0; j < name.length(); j++) {
    if (name[j] == characterToFind) {
        cout << "char is at index: " << j << endl;
    }
}
```

How do I then check if the inputted character doesnt exist in the `name` string array? I try to do the following:

```
if (characterToFind != name.find(characterToFind)) {
    cout<< "doesnt exist" << endl;
}
```

The if statement always seems to be true and runs the code even if the character that was inputted existed in the `name` string array.

Comment: Have a look what [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns. It's not the character but a position, if the character isn't found, `std::string::npos` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my approach was that I was doing was that in the if condition i was checking a 's' char vs a index position of an array.

instead, doing:

```
    if (name.find(characterToFind) == std::string::npos) {
       cout << "doesnt exist" << endl;
    }
```

this is checking if the character input is equal to a position that doesnt exist! This is true so it tells the user that the character entered does not exist.